# How to return function within functions while working with $this and classes for shortcodes

Tags: php, function, this, shortcode, public

I'm currently working on a WordPress plugin to add shortcodes into my WP page. 
Therefore I faced the topic of public functions, classes and $this variables. 
I have several files, but here I'll show only the one this question is related to.

I have the file "ShowCustomersShortcode.php".
In this file, I have this (very simplified) structure:

```
class ShowCustomers {

        public function pageContentFunction() {
                 /* php content here with a few html-elements like */

                foreach ($aaa->bbb as $ccc) {
                    $aaaHtml .= "
                    <div class='flex-item'>
                       <p>$ccc->customer</p>
                    </div>
                    ";
                }

                public function htmlContentFunction() {
                /* my whole html structure here with $php-variables like */
                echo <<<HTML
                    <div class='container'>
                         <h1>Customers</h1>
                    <div class='all-customers'>
                          $aaaHtml
                    </div>
                    HTML;
                 }
         }

      public function register($atts, $content = null) {
                 $this->pageContentFunction();
      }

      public function init() {
                 add_shortcode('display_customers_reviews', array($this, 
                 'register'));
      }

}
```

**The main question now is:** 
How can I call the function `htmlContentFunction()` within the `register()` function below to be able to access my variable `$aaaHtml` from my php in my `htmlContentFunction()`?

The reason for that is, to avoid putting the whole page into one function, rather into different functions which are called within one

I tried to keep it very simple. Thanks in advance for every advice how not to do it and what to change etc.!

Comment: You have a function inside function or it is a typo?

Comment: To be honest, no, it's not a typo. I thought I can call a function within a function like this. I struggle with how to do it. If this is not the right way or the wrong syntax, I'm open for a better/right way :)

Comment: Other functions have __no access__ to functions defined inside a function.

Comment: Thanks. So it's not even possible to pass a function as a paramter from another?